# Reading String of Varied Sizes // String Manipulation C++

Tags: c++, string, pointers, address-operator

So I just started learning C++ and My professor briefly went over Address (&) and Dereference (*) Operators. I'm not fluent in C++ but i have been searching around for parts and using common knowledge to combine into this code. It fails to build so Please Help!

Assignment- Write a program that keeps reading in strings of varied sizes. If an input string has length greater than one store it in a vector. When an input string has length one (a single character) you will output the string stored in your vector that has the first letter matching the input character. Keep doing this while you read string "quit".

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    string input;
    char* output;
    vector<string> name;

    while (input != "quit") {
        cin >> input;

        if (input.length == 1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < name.size; i++) {

                output = &name[i].at(0);

                if (input == output) {
                    cout << name[i];
                }
            }
        }
        else {

            name.push_back(input);
        }
    }

    //system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Although there is no error, it fails to compile" This is similar to "My car is blue, but it isn't blue"

Comment: Compiler errors usually contain the exact location of the problem, and a description of why the compiler can’t understand your code. It is much easier to identify issues if you see the error message; please copy that here.

Comment: `name.size` is a bug. `input.length` is a bug.

Comment: I'm a little rusty at C++, but should `input.length` be `input.length()` instead? If not, post the error code you're getting from your compile.

Comment: the reason for using char* is to point towards the first letter of the string that would be saved in a vector // is what I am thinking... im new to C++

Comment: I MEANT IT DOESNT BUILD! sorry i said compiled but fixed it

Comment: In addition to whatever the compiler error is, you’re comparing a `string` to a `char` pointer. They’re different types, so this only works because `std::string` explicitly provides a method to make the comparison, and that method looks at the *sequence* of characters pointed to by `output`, not just the one character, so that line should be changed even though it doesn’t have a compiler error. It’s also more standard to use a `for` loop with iterators, preferably a range-based `for` like `for (string& output : name)`, instead of indexing.

Comment: If it fails to build you have errors - your statement to the contrary does not make sense. Please provide the **exact** error messages your compiler is giving you

Comment: @AngelSnavely You were correct the first time; it doesn’t compile. Compilation is part of building, so the more specific term is useful. It’s still weird to say “Although there is no error, it fails to build”. If it doesn’t build, then it does not work correctly, and therefore does have an error. That’s like saying “My car is fine, but it fails to start”. If your car fails to start, it obviously isn’t fine.

Comment: `output = &name[i].at(0);` this will throw an exception after an empty line is read in, this is another bug in your code that you don't even know about. `if (input == output)` -- this does not compare the first character of `input`, the `std::string`, with the single character that `output` points to. This is what you want to do, but this is not what this comparison does. A computer never does what you want it to do, but only what you tell it to do. For more information, and how to do this comparison correctly, see your C++ book.

Comment: is the If statement correct where (input.length() == 1); the goal of the statement is to read the string and to determine if it has one character in it

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself: `void main() { string input="A"; if (input.length() == 1) std::cout << "Yes"; else std::cout << "No"; }` -- you can figure out the answer to your own question all by yourself, instead of waiting for someone else to tell you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string input;
    vector<string> name;

    cin >> input;

    while (input != "quit") {

        if (input.length() == 1) {

            for (int i = 0; i < name.size(); i++) {

                if (input[0] == name[i][0]) {
                    cout << name[i] <<endl; 
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            name.push_back(input);
        }
        cin >> input;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```